# Web-based or Desktop application 360 image viewer

Tags: imageview, 360-degrees

I'm looking for a 360 degrees images viewer. Either a web-based or a Desktop application, but one that is easy and intuitive to use.
I have some 360 degrees images saved on my Dropbox and am looking for a fast and easy way to view these images.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [RICOH THETA desktop app (Windows, MacOS)](https://theta360.com/en/support/download/) should work fine even with 360 degree pictures taken with other cameras.